# What does Anatoly say to Oliver in Russian in Arrow S5E16?

Tags: dialogue, arrowverse, arrow

What does Anatoly say to Oliver in Russian at minute 20 of Season 5 Episode 16 of *Arrow*?

> And you believed her? [Speaks Russian] Oliver, whatever you think is inside you is inside you.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your question includes what Anatoly says. Are you asking about what it means?

Comment: The part that says [Speaks Russian] is the missing string.

Comment: Is there a link to a video of this scene available?

Comment: For the next couple of weeks, *Arrow* Season 5 Episode 16 is [legally available to watch online on CW's official website](http://cwtv.com/shows/arrow/checkmate/?play=24233009-9afd-45ed-a33d-b63ec1369171) (CW is the television network that airs the show in the United States).

Answer (score 2):

Anatoly says one Russian word after the line "And you believed her?".

**глупый (glupyy)**

It means stupid.